# Received `NotActivated` error when debugging my foundry test

Tags: foundry, opcode, push0

I have hand-written a smart contract in opcodes. The first few opcodes are as such:

```
PUSH1 0x20
CALLDATALOAD
CALLER
PUSH0
SLOAD
ADD
```

However, all my tests for this contract keep breaking at `PUSH0`. When I debug the test with `--debug`, the call seems to revert without a `REVERT` opcode being hit. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to you not using the correct `evm_version`. Some versions of the EVM only support certain opcodes. Be sure you set the correct version in your `foundry.toml`.

For `PUSH0`, you'd need to use at least `shanghai`. Update your `foundry.toml` as such:

```
[profile.default]
evm_version = 'shanghai'
```